# Linq to SQL - Stored Procedure Query for Login

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, crud

I'm working on a login Windows Form using Linq to SQL, any idea whats next on this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_VERIFYADMIN
(
    @Username varchar(30) = NULL ,
    @Passwords varchar(30) = NULL
)

AS SELECT * FROM ADMIN
WHERE Username = @Username and Passwords = @Passwords
```

And now I am working on my `clsUserAuthentication`, before I proceed with my windows form any idea what do I put in my `clsUserAuthentication` and windows form?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Likewise, dont use cls* as a prefix for classes.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done so far is the Database part (backend).

You will have to work on the User Interface (front-end):

- create the form in C# with 2 textboxes
- link your application with Database using Connection String (from config file)
- call the stored procedure with parameter for UserName and Password

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your approach with this before continuing too far. A more common pattern is to

1. Get the credentials (username, password)from the user
2. Get the hashed password and salt from the
   database for this user
3. Hash the user supplied password
4. Compare the hashes.

There is an [OK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Aa545602(v=CS.70).aspx) article on MSDN about how to make hashes and salts.

With regards to your original question, this approach obviates the need for the proc entirely, as you can just get the user entity that matches the name and do the comparison in an easier to work with place.